# How to stop backscatter email spam

Tags: spam, spamassassin

I know I can't do anything about people spoofing my email address, but what can I do about all those annoying bounce-mails?

I get 5-10 "Undeliverable mail" a day, but I don't know how I can filter them.

I don't think I can run them through sa-learn because real "Undeliverable mail" could get caught in the filter that way, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop people from using my domain to send spam?](http://serverfault.com/questions/415533/how-to-stop-people-from-using-my-domain-to-send-spam)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I think you **can** do something about people spoofing your address; I strongly advocate SPF, with a strong policy on unapproved hosts (`-all`).

I know that not every ISP out there checks SPF on incoming email, but a surprising number do, and spammers are intelligent - since they're picking a forged sender in order to maximise delivery, they'll avoid forging a sender who will automatically be rejected by a significant fraction of ISPs, even though that fraction is well below 1.000.

Since I started publishing strong SPF records, I've had almost no backscatter at all.

You can find more out about SPF at [www.openspf.org](http://www.openspf.org/).

Comment: Even now gmail happily sends bounces generated by spam with failed spf result. But it seems it prevents at least some of the backscatter.