# Hacked server or someone is email spoofing

Tags: email, domain

I will like to know if this is possible if so how? Or is it someone who has access to the email and sending emails via my domain name!

I have viewed the source of the email everything seems to be legit except the ip address witch is form a different country

The domain belongs to large organization and i'm assuming that the domain and emails are protected against basic abuses, thats the part i dont understand!

me.at@my.domain.eu // OK

ip address // NOT OK

Comment: What is the question? Can someone spoof your email address? Yes they can. It's a trivial thing to do.

Comment: [Might want to see this thread](http://serverfault.com/a/415564/118258).  Of course, with the almost no information you've shared, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Re your edit: It is either your domain or the domain of a large organization... Also, there is no perfect protection for this. It's really easy to spoof a mail address (in some way, e-mail was designed to make this easy!) and many mail systems still do nothing or not enough to prevent it. The thing is: The owner of the domain can only help with things like SPF or DKIM, but if mail server owners don't use this information, the domain owner can do nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Spoofing an email address is simple and requires essentially zero technical know-how.

You should set up [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) (and DKIM wouldn't hurt) on your legitimate email so email servers can identify the spoofing as spam.

Comment: the domain belongs to large organization and i'm assuming that the domain and emails are protected against basic abuses, thats the part i dont understand!

Comment: The nature of the protocols used for email make it impossible to prevent email spoofing. Email was developed before spoofing and spam. Things like SPF and DKIM, when properly implemented, can help receiving servers determine whether incoming email is legitimate.

Comment: The receiving side also has to do SPF lookup validation and hard fail if it wants to take SPF serious.  This "large organization" likely has SPF records in place.

Comment: @Power-Mosfet Unfortunately, in my experience, the larger the organization the more likely they are open to basic abuses.  Organizations like banks, governments, airlines, couriers and the like rarely have SPF records.